# Validating a form that is used to create a record

Tags: php

I have code to validate my form before trying to upload anything.

I think I have nested the if statements incorrectly and that's why its not working properly.

I have put my PHP and HTML form code in a fiddle for anyone who is willing to have a look:    https://jsfiddle.net/1htqcyun/

Here is a snippet of the PHP:

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

//if the year is left empty then show error, if not then test_input
if (empty($_POST["year"])) {
$yearErr = "*enter a year";
} else {
$year = test_input($_POST["year"]);
}

//if the description is left empty then show error 
if (empty($_POST["description"])) {
$descriptionErr = "*enter a description";
  } else {
$description = test_input($_POST["description"]);
  }

// If the date has not been selected in the drop down, and the select is left at "Please Select" value = 0
if(isset($_POST['dateID']) && $_POST['dateID'] == '0'){
    $decadeErr = "*select a decade";    
}

 else {
$dateID = test_input($_POST["dateID"]);
  }
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing or anything else? Also, why are your 'select box' being retrieved by GET instead of the others which are POST

Comment: that is a mistake, i thought i'd taken that out. I will change it back.

Comment: Also have you tried replacing `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` with `if ( !empty($_POST) ) {` ? since I think request_method also has a chance of returning `option`

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: If i enter nothing in any of the fields and click upload, it returns the errors. But the wrong error appears on the image part which says "file already exists". And if put information into any of the other boxes it goes to a blank page and doesnt upload anything..

Comment: I've been going through your code but so far I can't see anything really wrong besides the lack of prepared statements. Before I continue, may I ask if you've made sure `img/` is writeable by either the Apache user (probebly "www-data", asuming you're using Apache as server) or the proper chmods? Or, in case of a Windows server, the directory is not to set "Read only"?

Comment: img/ is writeable as i had y code working before i tried adding the validation and it was uploading images to the database and local www folder @icecub

Answer (score 0):

FYI - using jsFiddle for a PHP example is not helpful. Try http://phpfiddle.org/

I think the issue is in calling the `$_FILE` variable too soon, on line 10 of your code:

`$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);`

If you're running the script the first time, this would fail. I would change this to:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
     if(!empty($_FILES["file_upload"])){
          $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);
          $uploadOk = 1;
          $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          $check = getimagesize($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"]);
     }
     $year = $description = $dateID = "";
     $yearErr = $descriptionErr = $decadeErr = "";
     // continue the rest of your $_POST handling...
}
```

This way if nothing is posted, as would be the case on it's first run, the script does not try to handle items that have not yet been posted.